# undefined method `before_filter' for ActionController::Base:Class (NoMethodError) Did you mean? before_action

Tags: ruby-on-rails

every time i try to add "devise_security_extension" gem i get the above error, But there is no "before_filter" in my code, i have replaced it with "before_action".

Comment: That gem hasn't been updated in 6 years and is very unlikely to work with modern versions of Rails or Devise. Audit your dependencies before you add them to the gemfile my friend...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind, the problem was i was using an outdated gem. updating everything was the solution.